# Just starting to evaluate - some basic questions

Tags: authentication

We are just in the CMS evaluation stage, so, I have some early questions:

1. We don't want to create another layer of user logins, can Craft authenticate users using oauth or active directory?
2. As Craft users -> Why is Craft better than Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla?

Comment: Hi Chip, welcome to Craft Stack Exchange. While your first question is legitimate, your second question is highly subjective. For this reason, this question will be closed as "primarily opinion-based". If you'd like to delete your second question, we can re-open this thread. To ask broadly about "Why is Craft better", I'd suggest posting on the [Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226) instead.

Answer (score 2):

For 1), check out Dukt's [oAuth plugin](https://dukt.net/craft/oauth) for Craft.  Not aware of any Active Directory plugins that have been written yet and not seeing any on [here](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins), either.

The second question is pretty subjective, so not sure if that's the best type of question for SE, but I'll let someone else take a stab at it if they want.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to initially reply when I read your response.

Answer (score 2):

For 2, which is indeed subjective but nevertheless: Coming from WordPress, I always tell my customers that Craft is way better for us because I don't have to strip down a CMS before starting a project. WordPress did a lot of things without us even knowing about it. With Craft, I start with a blank sheet and work my way up, knowing exactly why things work the way they work.

Other plusses:

- Flexibility and usability: The combination of Twig and Craft's sections and fields gives you more flexibility than WP would ever give you with custom fields. Twig's learning curve seems steep at first, but once you get used to it, you'll never want anything else.

  - Caching: Craft's {% cache %} tag makes caching page content easier than ever. No extra plugins needed.
  - Multiple locales? No problem! Setting up multiple locales takes minutes, not ages. Again, no extra plugins needed (but, to be honest, you'd need Craft's Pro license).
  - Found a bug? The guys at P&T have proven to be a dedicated and professional team. It wouldn't be the first time I find a bug on thursday, and it's fixed in next friday's update.
  - Matrix field. To hard to explain, look it up ([here, for example](http://buildwithcraft.com/features/matrix)). WordPress, eat that.

I'm getting a bit carried away here, and I think these are just a few of the many advantages of Craft over whatever open source CMS out there. If you want to know more, let me know!

Comment: Thank you.  I did not reply initially, but, these comments are very helpful!